# How to produce a pdf with modifications visible with Overleaf?

Tags: revision-control, overleaf

I know (and appreciate) how to compare two version of the same document by [using "versions" and "compare" in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/154-a-first-look-at-the-new-version-comparison-feature).

[image]

But I would like to produce a PDF showing these modifications and their authors, with colors, as a word processing software (ie LibreOffice) would do.

Comment: latexdiff can be used online as well (not requiring Perl, command line or any other programs): [https://3142.nl/latex-diff/](https://3142.nl/latex-diff/)

Answer (score 6):

Looking beyond Overleaf, use the [latexdiff](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff?lang=en) package, which is a perl script that compares and marks the differences between two .tex files.

Also, [BaKoMa TeX](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/), (at time of writing cost is $122.05) has this functionality, in WYSIWYG form, using latexdiff.

Comment: Ideally I would like this inside Overleaf, unfortunately it is currently, aa in feb 2016, [under consideration by the developers](http://support.overleaf.com/forums/137318-feedback/suggestions/5128241-latexdiff).

Answer (score 6):

Surprisingly this problem is still there as in Aug 2021.
The biggest challenge of using latexdiff with Overleaf is we usually have many .tex files in a project. Inspired by this post: http://dropbearcode.blogspot.com/2011/09/multiple-file-latex-diff.html, I wrote a Python script that merges all your .tex files into a single one so that you can easily use latexdiff.

You can just pip install to use it:

```
pip3 install latex_proj_tool
python3 -m latex_proj_tool flat my_project/main.tex --output out.tex
```

Check out this repo for details: https://github.com/comaniac/latex-proj-tool

My use case:

1. Download two versions you want to diff from the Overleaf project history.
2. Use the script to make two .tex files: "old.tex" and "new.tex".
3. Follow the instructions in the repo to generate "diff.tex".
4. Upload "diff.tex" to the Overleaf project.
5. Set "diff.tex" as the "Main document" in the Overleaf project temporary and re-compile.
6. You'll get the diff result in the preview, and you can download the PDF as you always do.
7. Set the Main document back to your main document and continue working.

The reason of step 4-6 is I have lots of figures and I need them to generate a diff PDF file correctly. You can also compile the diff PDF file locally if you have pdflatex in your environment.

Comments and pull requests are welcome.